# VBA change negative range to positive

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change the negative values to positive based on a dynamic range. By dynamic I mean that the row number might change.

For example

```
rowStart = 10
rowEnd   = 20
```

From these I need to change the values in this range to positive. I'm trying the following but I'm getting an error:

```
Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd).Value = _
    Abs(Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd).Value)
```

The error I get is: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you just Find & Replace any hyphens with ""?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must **loop over the items**:

```
Sub ksdjfh()
    Dim r As Range

    rowStart = 10
    rowEnd = 20

    For Each r In Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd)
        r.Value = Abs(r.Value)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it in whole that way.

Either Loop:

```
For i = rowStart to rowEnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = Abs(ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value)
Next i
```

Or you can set it using Evaluate:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd).Value = Evaluate("INDEX(ABS(" & Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd).Address & "),)")
```

Comment: Nice `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
rowStart = 10
rowEnd = 20
For Each myCell In Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd)
    myCell.Value = Abs(myCell.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Does your number format allow for simply removing the negative signs (i.e. *hyphens*)?

```
Dim rowStart As Long, rowEnd As Long
rowStart = 10
rowEnd = 20
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("K" & rowStart & ":K" & rowEnd).Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Place in an array and loop over the items (might be faster than updating the range if it's a big range):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rowStart As Long, rowEnd As Long
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim vRange() As Variant
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    rowStart = 10
    rowEnd = 20

    With Sheet1
        'Define the range.
        Set rRange = .Range(.Cells(rowStart, 1), .Cells(rowEnd, 1))
    End With
    vRange = rRange

    'Loop through the values - consider R to mean Row.
    For R = 1 To UBound(vRange, 1)
        vRange(R, 1) = Abs(vRange(R, 1))
    Next R

    rRange.Value = vRange

End Sub
```